# 90's sci-fi TV film with aliens or cyborgs throwing masks that attach to people's faces

Tags: story-identification, tv

**NOTE: Solved and Updated** I've added what does not match the TV-Show in the topic, noted as "correction" or "false"

This might be a tricky one but I'll do my best once again.

**Story** (fragments I remember)
The film (**correction**: *TV-mini series*), which most likely was released direct-to-VHS around the mid-90s (also the time I watched it), takes place on Earth (a US city environment) and include some kind of aliens/otherworldly beings who control humans by 1: throwing some sort and bio-mechanical mask (**false**: *it's a parasite that latches on to the face like a facehugger from the Alien franchise although they are indeed thrown at one point*) on the victims faces (kind of "launched" like projectiles from their palms) and then 2: sort of welding or activating the masks with something that looked like stick with a light on it if remember correctly. The masks cover the nose and mouth of the human victims who then turn into drones (think the Borg from the Star Trek franchise) - **the latter is false**

The masks were dark in color (**correction**: *light, but the breathing masks the aliens used were dark so I must've mixed these two up*), maybe aesthetically inspired by H.R Giger's work on Alien (**correction**: *only slightly similar design-wise*)

**Scenes from the film**: At one point, the camera (possibly binocular POV from the protagonist) pans across the side of a parked bus at night, showing several humans wearing these alien masks (**correction**: the beings with masks were aliens)
At the end of the film, I think the main character used a mask against a villain but I'm not entirely sure (**false**)
The film partly or mostly takes place at night in an urban environment (**correction** *partly at night*)

**Production year**: likely mid-90's

**Genre**: definitely sci-fi taking place in in the 90's as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of research I managed to solve it! It was a TV mini-series called [The Invaders](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112018/?ref_=kw_li_tt) from 1995.

Plot (from the IMDB link in the title) *A man named Nolan Wood tries to stop an invasion of Earth by aliens disguised as humans.*

[Full show](https://youtu.be/o5rXgriUfBE) (YouTube link)

Update: Certain scenes matched my memories

Camera POV on the bus with the aliens and indoctrinated humans, at night
[image]

Parasite "mask" thrown/launched from the palm of a disguised alien
[image]

And activated/injected (I remembered it as welded) with a device with a stick and a light on it.
[image]

Comment: Uh so can I pat myself on the back and give my own post a thumbs up? XD
EDIT: Damn, it didn't work lol.

Comment: ^_^ Yeah, but it does count as an accepted answer for you, which means you may be able to earn badges. Although, even self answers need more details. How do we know this show matches? Can you provide summaries? Screenshots? A trailer?

Comment: You're right, I'll add some more info and details, and then update my topic accordingly.

Comment: *sighs* ...here's this guy been a member less than a week and he's casually dropping photos and screenshots into his posts.            I've been a member for over 9 years and still lack the technical ability to do the same. *Walks away with his hands in back pockets while muttering and randomly kicking at small stones*

Comment: Lol hey don't feel bad @Danny! I've been a gamefaqs member for almost 20 years so I've learned a thing or two from that site :) you can do this, just try different options and you'll learn in no time just (*Shia Labeouf voice*) DO IT :D